# How can I mathematically compare two unknown types in Scala?

Tags: scala, compare

I'm writing a little script evaluator function.  It takes two arguments and a comparison operator like this:

```scala
    def compare[T,U](a:T, op:String, b:U): Boolean = {
      op match {
        case "==" => a == b
        case "<"  => a < b
        // and so on with other comparators...
      }
    }
```

This code won't compile.  The '<' operator doesn't work on the generic types.  I couldn't find a parent class for numeric types with the '<' operator, so I can't even do something like:  `def compare[T<:Numeric,U<:Numeric](...)`

Is there a way to do this (or a library)?  Right now I can only test equal/not-equal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, every time you want some kind of *interface* for common operations on multiple types, the answer is a **Typeclass**.
In this particular case, you can use [`scala.math.Ordering`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/Ordering.html).

```
import scala.math.Ordering
import Ordering.Implicits._

def compare[T: Ordering](a: T, op: String, b: T): Boolean = op match {
  case "==" => a == b
  case "<"  => a < b
  // and so on with other comparators...
}
```

And now you can use it like this.

```
compare(10, "==", 15) //false
compare(10, "==", 10) // true
compare(10, "<", 10) // false
compare(10, "<", 11) // true
```

Answer (score 2):

edit: Luis' answer involving using a single parameter type and relying on type inference is likely the best overall solution. If you are set on using two separate types, here are some options:

Since you are attempting to compare two separate classes, you cannot directly inherit a trait member implementation that will fit both. However, if you can provide function literals that will convert a class to a Double, you can use the following code.

```
def compare[T,U](a: T, op:String, b: U, tToDouble: T => Double, uToDouble: U => Double): Boolean = {
      op match {
        case "==" => tToDouble(a) == uToDouble(b)
        case "<"  => tToDouble(a) < uToDouble(b)
        // and so on with other comparators...
      }
    }
//example using Int
println(compare(1, "<", 2, (x:Int) => x.toDouble, (y:Int) => y.toDouble)) //true
```

Unfortunately, we cannot use Ordering or Numeric, because those are parameterized traits and the expectation is for comparison against themselves. Another method is just to accept a comparator function that accepts objects of each type whenever you wish to compare two types of objects.

```
def compare[T,U](a: T, op:String, b: U, comparator: (T,U) => Int): Boolean = {
      op match {
        case "==" => comparator(a,b) == 0
        case "<"  => comparator(a,b) < 0
        // and so on with other comparators...
      }
    }

println(compare[Int, Int](1, "<", 2, (a,b) => a-b)) //true
```

Comment: I do not think the second type parameter is needed. First, from a mathematical point of view, it even does not make sense to compare to elements of different sets _(types)_. Second, usually when one compares two different types like `Int` and `Double` one usually only wan to treat both as the greater type _(which type inference will solve it only using one type parameter)_.

Comment: I agree with you. Editing my post to highlight that.